# Is it possible to pass a determined $MYSQL_ROOT_PASS to MySQL docker from outside docker? If so how?

Tags: mysql, docker, pi

So I'm writing an install script and because I haven't been able to find a solid MySQL replacement on armfh (the db must be MySQL compatible), I'm using a community on that works, however it does not initiate the db as it should. it requires me to pass the following argument.

`mysql -h"db" -u"root" -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" "$MYSQL_DATABASE" < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_db.sql`

From inside the docker. Problem is I want this to flow naturally as a smooth install script. I've tried using the following command to pass the document and get a password prompt:

```
docker exec -it db bash -c "mysql -h"db" -u"root" -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" "$MYSQL_DATABASE" < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_db.sql"
```

If also tried:

```
docker exec -it db bash -c "mysql -h'db' -u'root' -p'$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' '$MYSQL_DATABASE' < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_db.sql
```

FwIW: I used the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 64 | head -n 1)` to define the password. And if I manually enter the docker send command 1 (in quotations) the db initiates.

So to summarize my question: Is it possible to pass a command like the above to activate the 1_db.sql file from outside docker?

Any help would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a command like the above to activate the
>   1_db.sql file from outside docker?

you can try something like

```
cat 1_db.sql  | docker exec -i test bash -c 'mysql  -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE'
```

also, remember when you try `exec bash -c "mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"`it will for `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in the host, not inside container, use single quotes.

> determined `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS` to MySQL docker from outside docker? If so
>   how?

```
docker exec -i test bash -c 'echo mysql docker password is $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
```

Comment: So in my situation, replace test.sql with 1_db.sql?

i guess I'm kind of confused on how I can combine your suggestion with my situation. 

thank you for the response

Comment: Yes exactly, replace the file name

Comment: I ran 
`
cat 1_db.sql | docker exec -i db bash -c 'mysql 
-uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE'



and didn't get an error... so maybe it worked? I'll have to try it on a fresh run of my install. Hopefully it works.

thank you